# Dictionary from a string skips new line character

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, decode, encode

**EDIT**

(C#) I have an dictionary coded as string and I want to retrieve it back.
The problem is that, I use regex and I get dictionary without '\n' key.

Here is code preview for console application: [dictionaries example](http://pastebin.com/QXSBYu8S)

If you can see, the first and second dictionaries doesn't match. Sorry guys for bad question format.

Comment: It's *really* hard to understand your question with images like this. It would be much, much easier to help you if you could provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. I strongly suggest you separate the dictionary part from the regex part - I suspect this has nothing to do with dictionaries. (And "I try to get 'byte' number 'char'" makes no sense...)

Comment: Don't include _pictures_ of text. Include the text instead.

Comment: "a dictionary coded as string" what does this mean. Could you show a piece of code where this dictionary is built and some example data as well?

Comment: Sorry guys, I couldn't explain correctly what was my problem, but AmatuerDev could understand what I want to achieve and solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your question isn't clear enough. I will have to make some assumptions here. Try adding `RegexOptions.Singleline` option to your Regex.

```
var dictionary = Regex.Matches(frequencies, @".\d+.", RegexOptions.Singleline).Cast<Match>().ToDictionary(x => Convert.ToByte(x.Value[0]), x => int.Parse(x.Value.Substring(1, x.Value.Length - 2)));
```

[Test Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0i9LVV)

Comment: thank you very much, it solved my problem ! Also I'm sorry that I couldn't clearly explain what my problem is. :)